# Toolbar arrow don't work in PreferenceFragment in NavigationDrawer

Tags: android, toolbar, android-preferences, preferencefragment

I'm using PreferenceFragment that I launch from the NavigationDrawer. In the preferenceFragment I show the toolbar. All looks good, but when I press the arrow in the toolbar to come back it doesn't work. I can see in the log this:

```
D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
```

But don't do nothing. The only way to come back is press button back in the device

Some help will be appreciated.

This is my code: 
PreferenceFragment:

```
public class AnPreferenceActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.pref_with_actionbar);
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame, new SettingsPreference())
                .commit();
    }

    public static class SettingsPreference extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        }
    }
}
```

Layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:navigationContentDescription="@string/abc_action_bar_up_description"
        app:navigationIcon="?attr/homeAsUpIndicator"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:title="@string/action_settings" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/appbar" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: did you handle back press in menu items ? onOptionMenu when pressed android.R.id.home you should **backPressed()**

Comment: Hi Amir, not sure if I understand you. I'm something new in android. Can you show me a bit of code of this, please??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `onCreate()` of your fragment first you should declare it has option Menu:

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

Then you should handle your own menu:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case android.R.id.home:
            // close fragment here
            getActivity().getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            return true;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

If you need more Menu create new menu item:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Accessing to toolbar from fragment is not good approach you should handle it in better way. There are lots of thread about this issue out there. (in fact Activity should handle Toolbar behaviour)